# sql select duplicates by ignore seconds in date format

Tags: c#, sql

in my table Date store with seconds like 26-06-2014 09:24:25

i want to select duplicate values order by [Date] it takes seconds portion also 
but i need to select duplicates order by [Date] without seconds part

my current code is

```
WITH x AS (SELECT *, rn = row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Date, Product,ExpiryDate ORDER BY Date)FROM Eod) Select * FROM x WHERE rn > 1
```

if i have two Dates like 26-06-2014 09:24:25 & 26-06-2014 09:24:30
then i need any one of two records
but it shows nothing by taking seconds prt also.I want to ignore seconds part to show a record

Comment: Use `cast([Date] as Date)`

Comment: i just want to exclude seconds part from time your code excludes total time part

Comment: you try group by for example  select  Date, Product,ExpiryDate
 from        Eod 
 Group by Date, Product,ExpiryDate ORDER BY Date

Comment: it works with CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),Date)